# iTextSharp - Force text below image

Tags: itext

My issue with images and iTextSharp is that I want to put a header in and the have the text below that point.

I can display the image and wrap the text but not get it to display below, even when adding New paragraph.

I am assuming there is some command around the aligmnent but I am struggling to find it even when looking at tutorials such as http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/87/iTextSharp-Working-with-images

```vb
'Import Image
    Dim vImagePath = "C:\sites\images\" & "Logo.jpg"
    Dim jpg As Image = Image.GetInstance(vImagePath)

    jpg.ScaleToFit(139.0F, 106.0F)
    jpg.Alignment = Image.ALIGN_RIGHT Or Image.TEXTWRAP
    jpg.IndentationLeft = 7.0F
    jpg.SpacingAfter = 9.0F
    jpg.BorderWidthTop = 6.0F
    jpg.BorderColorTop = Color.WHITE
    document.Add(jpg)


 '##Main Document Header
        Dim tableHeader As New PdfPTable(1)  ' Number in brackets is number of columns           
        tableHeader.DefaultCell.Border = Rectangle.NO_BORDER
        Dim phFirst As Phrase = New Phrase("Title", HeaderFont)
        tableHeader.AddCell(phFirst)
        document.Add(tableHeader)
```

Comment: What's `vSingleImage` and what does `ImageAdd.ImageSingle` do? You're using `Color.WHITE` which means you're using the old and unsupported version 4.1.6 or older, have you tried your code with the most recent 5.5? I just tried your code by adding `jpg` directly to the `document` and it appears above the text as expected. Can you post an image of what you're seeing and what you're expecting?

Comment: vImageName is "picture.jpg"

Comment: What does this line do? `vSingleImage = ImageAdd.ImageSingle(vImageName)`

Comment: Also, you aren't actually using the `jpg` variable even above.

Comment: Modified code so it should read better now!